# Want options under select in IE, one by one

Tags: vba

I want option value in MsgBox one by one, like:

```
Week:-1 12-May-2019
Week:-2 19-May-2019
Week:-3 26-May-2019
Week:-4 02-Jun-2019
```

Html:

```html
<table id="tblMain" cellspacing="1" class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable" border="0" style="border-color:SaddleBrown;font-size:Small;">
  <tr style="background-color:#3C8DBC;">
    <td colspan="2"><select name="cmbWeeks" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;cmbWeeks\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="cmbWeeks" class="form-control" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:9pt;">
        <option value="12-May-2019">Week:-1 12-May-2019</option>
        <option value="19-May-2019">Week:-2 19-May-2019</option>
        <option value="26-May-2019">Week:-3 26-May-2019</option>
        <option value="02-Jun-2019">Week:-4 02-Jun-2019</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="">[Select Week]</option>

    </select><br />
    <select name="ddllocation" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ddllocation\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="ddllocation" class="form-control" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:9pt;">
        <option selected="selected" value="GPC">GPC</option>
```

Comment: From where do you run your VBA and how do you access the html code given?

Comment: please share your coding attempt at this. [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: Below for loop is throughing an error                                                                        Set iframe = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").Item(0).contentWindow
Set tbl = iframe.Document.getElementsByTagName("table").Item(1)
Set td = tbl.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(0)
Set slect = td.getElementsByTagName("select").Item(0)
MsgBox slect.selectedIndex
MsgBox td.innerText
For j = 0 To slect.selectedIndex
MsgBox tbl.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(j).innerText
Next

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following css selector combination assuming your iframe reference is correct

```
Dim options As Object, i As Long
Set options = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelectorAll("[name=cmbWeeks] option")
For i = 0 To options.Length - 1
    MsgBox options.Item(i).Value
Next
```

Comment: WOW, it resolve my issue, Thanks, one more thing, how could i select one propdown and the IE will change as per selection (onchange)

Comment: ie.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelector("[name=cmbWeeks]").SelectedIndex = 1 etc

Comment: Thanks a ton QHarr, I go the solution to my queries.

Comment: Hi Again
The above code is working for week selection but not to select time
<td style="white-space:nowrap;">Master Timings</td><td><select name="ddlSTSun" id="ddlSTSun" onChange="return ChangeAllSTET(frmRosterInfoTLEmp,&#39;ddlSTSun&#39;,&#39;ddlST1Sun02&#39;);" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:9pt;">
<option value="01:00">01:00</option> 
<option value="02:00">02:00</option> 
<option value="03:00">03:00</option> 
<option value="04:00">04:00</option> 
<option value="05:00">05:00</option> 
<option value="06:00">06:00</option> 
<option value="07:00">07:00</option>

Comment: ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelector("[name=cmbWeeks]").selectedIndex = "Week:-2 19-May-2019" 'Range("AA10").Text
ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelector("[name=cmbWeeks]").FireEvent ("onchange")
Sleep 5000
ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelector("[name=ddlSTMon]").selectedIndex = "12:00" 'Range("D13").Text
ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelector("[name=ddlSTMon]").FireEvent ("onchange")